# C++ 'using' and 'using typename' in a header file

Tags: c++, header, using

In the C++ code below, could somebody explain what each of these lines mean in the `private` section? I have tried looking it up, but I still cannot figure out what they do.

I understand that `using` is the equivalent to `typedef` in C.  So:

```
using the_graph = graph<T_node, T_edge1, T_allocator, T_size>;
```

Means that you use `the_graph`.

But, in this instance, why would you call the scope resolution operator on it?

I don't think that it is any of the 4 methods [described here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/).

```
template <class T_node, class T_edge1, class T_edge2, class T_allocator, class T_size = uint32_t>
class graph : private virtual graph<T_node, T_edge1, T_allocator, T_size>, private virtual graph<T_node, T_edge2, T_allocator, T_size>
{

public:

    using the_graph = graph<T_node, T_edge1, T_allocator, T_size>;


private:

    using typename the_graph::node_list_iterator;
    using the_graph::node_begin;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `using` directive is used to bring a name into the current scope that otherwise is not.

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar {};
};

int main()
{
   Bar b1; // Not ok. Bar is not in scope yet.

   using Foo::Bar;
   Bar b2; // Ok. Bar is now in scope.
}
```

When a name is dependent upon a template parameter, the standard requires that you use the elaborate form

```
using typename the_graph::node_list_iterator;
```

After that line, you can use `node_list_iterator` as a typename.

Had `the_graph` not been a class template, you could have used the simpler form

```
using the_graph::node_list_iterator;
```

Further reading: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

Those `using` make visible the associated name and avoid ambiguity.

Both bases should have type `node_list_iterator` and method(s) `node_begin`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the definition and the declaration of a template, the keyword `typename` is used to specify that the qualified-id (ie `some_name::some_member`) is a type and not a variable. This keyword is necessary before template instantiation, because the compiler does not know the definition of `some_name`, and without `typename` it would supposes that `some_member` is a variable (or function).

Then the using directive `using typename::node_list_iterator` make `node_list_iterator` privately accessible from the `graph` class.